# Suppress part numbers in Exam Class

Tags: exam

When using the parts environment in the `exam` class, along with the `\answerline` command, the part number is listed twice, once before the part question and once before the part answerline.

If I don't need to say anything in the part question, is there a way to suppress the part number being typeset there?

If I don't use the parts environment at all and just use multiple `\answerline` commands they are all numbered with the questions number.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Name two colors.
    \begin{parts}
      % nothing to say in the parts
      \part\answerline
      \part\answerline
    \end{parts}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The above code shows sort of what I'm doing. I want the `\answerline` commands to have (a) and (b) but the `\part` commands also have (a) and (b) which I don't want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following two lines to your preamble.

```
\newcommand\stoplabeling{\def\makelabel##1{}}
\newcommand\resumelabeling{\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}
```

Then you can start and stop labeling by inserting these two commands in any list environment that uses `\item`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newcommand\stoplabeling{\def\makelabel##1{}}
\newcommand\resumelabeling{\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Name two colors.
    \begin{parts}
      \stoplabeling
      % nothing to say in the parts
      \part \answerline
      \part \answerline
      \resumelabeling
      \part Do you know another one? \answerline
    \end{parts}
  \end{questions}
Also works with other lists, like itemize.
\begin{itemize}
\item Marked item
\stoplabeling
\item Unmarked item with an enumerated list in it.
   \begin{enumerate}
     \item Marks are again active within every new list.
   \end{enumerate}
\item Another unmarked item: on the outer level still no label.
\resumelabeling
\item Marked item, since labeling has been resumed.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: amazing! perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have no good idea.

I tried to manipulate the counter `partnumber` (I found in the source code), but didn't suceed.

A workaround could be:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Define two colors
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \hrulefill
    \item \hrulefill
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Of course, you can fill in a `\strut` or change the `itemsep` distance, to give some room for a handwritten text.

Comment: I think that will work since i generally don't separate my points down to the part level. Thanks!

Comment: @Andy: You are welcome!  If it worked for you, you might mark it solved.

Comment: How is `\thequestion` defined? Try inside the document `\meaning\thequestion` and look after something like `\thepartnumber.\arabic{question}`...